# How to add listener for user location google maps sdk for iOS

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

How to add listener for user location changes google maps sdk for iOS?

Answer (score 4):

Hello the Google Maps SDK for iOS provides an observable property myLocation in the class GMSMapView.

```
/**
 * If My Location is enabled, reveals where the user location dot is being
 * drawn. If it is disabled, or it is enabled but no location data is available,
 * this will be nil.  This property is observable using KVO.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) CLLocation *myLocation;
```

For more information see my answer at:
[about positioning myself,some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266118/about-positioning-myself-some-problems/15291319#15291319)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** This answer is incorrect, see Robert's answer.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the Google Maps SDK for iOS which would notify you when the user's location changes.

So you would need to use Core Location (the [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) class) yourself to listen for location changes.