# didUpdateUserLocation in Google Maps?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am building an iOS app using storyboards and Google Maps. Using iOS6 - Apple maps has a method

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
}

Looking over the documentation online and the googleMaps.framework in xCode I did not find any clues to a similar method.

What I am trying to do is when a user reaches a marker on the map - let the user know that they reached that destination.

Does a method like shown above exist in google maps? and/or what do I need to do to achieve what I stated earlier.

Any guidance on this matter would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GMSMapView` class has a `myLocation` property, which you can observe for changes when the user's location moves. See this question for full details:

[about positioning myself,some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266118/about-positioning-myself-some-problems)

Another approach to look into could be the `startMonitoringForRegion:` method, which you can use to receive a notification when the user moves inside a region (eg, close to the destination marker):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:

Comment: The myLocation property seems to be doing the trick, thanks much