# How to add infoWindow to users current location in Google Maps v1.3 for iOS?

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I would like to add an infoWindow when the user taps their current location (blue dot) in the Google Maps API V1.3 for iOS.

I can get infoWindows on other markers but not to display above the users location. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Normal marker infoWindow]

[image: google current location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you go with the the 'default' user location, you can't. Because it isn't a real marker, the callbacks aren't fired.

What I did in our case is that I set `showsMyLocation=NO` but I rolled my own location. I  added another marker and used a `CLLocationManager` to position it according to THAT position..

So in pseudocode

```
- viewDidLoad
    map.showsUserLocation=NO;
    locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
}

- locationManager:didUpdateUserLocation:newLoc {
    if(!annotation) {
        annotation = [GMSMarker new];
        annotation.map = map;
    }
    annotation.position = newLoc;
}
```

=> own annotation that you can treat like any other marker!

Comment: thanks! that did the trick. I still wanted the blue dot so i dug around in the bundle and found it and set it as that markers icon. It doesn't give me the accuracy blue circle but its close enough for what I need. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative option, could you add a marker with a transparent icon at the user's current location?

You could use KVO to move the marker whenever the map view's myLocation value changes.

You can see some sample code for how to add an observer here (but instead of moving the camera, you could move your invisible marker):

[about positioning myself,some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266118/about-positioning-myself-some-problems)